# Script Command -- Extra space and return added to long input

Tags: bash, macos

I am creating a browser-based application for interacting with my local terminal, and I'm using the `script` command in the terminal (actually in a Java process) to feed input and capture output to display in the browser.

I have found that the virtual terminal inside the `script` process has 80 columns by default, and when a line of input exceeds that number, I see unexpected behavior.  When it reaches the length limit, it adds a space, then a return, then continues with the line.  For example, if I input the following:

```
user_name ~/my/current/directory$ ls /some/really/long/path/to/some/directory/somewhere
```

The following is what is actually transcribed (and forwarded to my browser app):

```
user_name ~/my/current/directory$ ls /some/really/long/path/to/some/directory/so ^Mmewhere
```

Notice the `so ^Mmewhere` instead of `somewhere`.

When I hit the `up` arrow after that to retrieve the last input, I get something different:

```
user_name ~/my/current/directory$ ls /some/really/long/path/to/some/directory/som^Mmewhere
```

This time, instead of the extra space character, it's duplicating the m: `som^Mmewhere`.

What is going on here?  Is it that the `script` command is really intended to produce text output for a human reader, and therefore favors visual formatting over executability?  Is there an alternative to `script` that would work better for my purpose?

---

**Edit**

I should have mentioned that I'm doing this in macOS Sierra.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: You are using the `man 1 script` command, the one described in the man page as "*useful for students who need a hardcopy record of aninteractive session as proof of an assignment*"? The one that specifically notes: "*BUGS Script places everything in the log file, including linefeeds and backspaces.*" The `^M` is a DOS *carriage return*. If you are using this `script`, it is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Linefeeds, backspaces, and ANSI escape sequences are fine.  As long as they are handled correctly, they help to produce correct output.  But this particular behavior produces incorrect output.  Anyway, is there a better alternative for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question.  Yes, I am using that command.

Comment: I think you have 2 things going on. One - lines are breaking at the `80` column limit - which I don't see as configurable and you are getting the embedded carriage returns there, and Second, your prompt cannot deal with embedded carriage returns when you arrow-up. (It corrupts `PS1` prompt and line character count)

Comment: I can configure the 80-character limit by putting `COLUMNS=10000` or some other ridiculous number in `~/.bashrc`. I don’t understand your second point.

Comment: Although I can change the number of columns and my program works fine, I just want to understand the problem rather than relying on a hacky solution

Comment: The line breaks you get with `script` are one issue, and the `up-arrow` is a separate issue (but related to trying to display a last command that now has an embedded CR) I don't know what you are using in java (I primarily use C),  but I suspect you are using the equivalent of `system (script .. stuff);` which is going to give you no end of fun handling all the stray garbage that `script` can return.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I do need to look again at my prompt, because I found some other issues with it while debugging other stuff. Maybe Java is adding more complexity, and maybe `script` isn’t the right tool. Is there an equivalent tool that allows me to interact with a virtual terminal session? I’m new at this, so I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: I think it will be subtle. I suspect what is happening is you issue a command from the browser environment which is then piped through `script` and executed (it has to capture the input as well as the output). In that process a `^M` (and more) is embedded in the command. When you attempt to redisplay the command with *up-arrow* the command now has as least one **non-printing** character in the command line that is **not escaped** in a way that can be handled with the default `PS1` prompt causing the command to appear broken at a different point (due to non-escaped embedded control chars)

Comment: [IBM Prompt Magic](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-tip-prompt/) and [Bash/Prompt customization - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization) are fairly good references for the prompt issue. Also see `man bash` under `PROMPTING`.

Comment: I should have thought of this before, but I got caught up in our discussion.  Actually, the examples I presented above came directly from a terminal session, not from the browser-to-java application.  I replicated everything in a terminal session in order to reproduce the problem without the extra complications.  My prompt for this session was as you see it above, `'user_name ~/my/current/directory$ '`. That string is exactly what I put in my `~/.bashrc` file. So this is happening within the `script` process, no matter where the input comes from, and the prompt shouldn't be the problem.